# How to prepend # on every routing path

Tags: angular, routes

In Angular 1, routing path is always prepended "#", but in Angular 4, it is not included.

I think there is a way to config this function because I saw it in ng-bootstrap demo:
https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home

Thank for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can set `useHash: true` when you import the `RouterModule`:

```
imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(myRoutes, {useHash: true})}
```